# Is there a way to display a message once a timer has reached 0 and then restart the timer?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, timertask

i want to display a message while inside of a javascript timer once it hits 0 and restarts.
The code for my timer and my other question like this that hasnt been answered:

[How do you display a message once a javascript function restarts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083534/how-do-you-display-a-message-once-a-javascript-function-restarts)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You were missing the correct implementation of `window.clearInterval`

```
var c = 10;
var t;

function timedCount() {
    document.getElementById('txt').value = c;
    c = c - 1;
    if (c == 0){
        clearTimeout(t);
        //alert something here
        c = 10;
        doMining();
    }

}

function doMining() {
    t = setInterval(function () {
        timedCount();
    }, 1000);
}
```

The signature of [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) is as follows.

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay);
```

Comment: can you explain how the following line works.                                    t = setInterval(function () {
        timedCount();
    }, 1000);